# Why I can't read replicate data in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, replicate

I have created a replica Set with 4 MongoD running.
port: 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020

Very standard.  I followed the instruction as in the documentation.

Then I set 2020 be the primary one.  And then I insert data.

Then I go back and login to another one. e.g. ./mongo localhost:2017

and try to do a find().
it returns:

```
error: { "$err" : "not master", "code": 10107}
```

Why ??  I tried on other replicates and all gave  me the same error.

---

I also notice that I get this error in the mongod output when I insert data.

```
 Failed to allocate new file: /home/ec2-user/db/r04/test.1, size: 134217728, aborting.
```

I'm no clue what's going on yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set [slaveOk](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Querying#Querying-slaveOk) when querying from slaves.

Comment: thanks.. and I have to run db.getMongo().setSlaveOk(); in the master mongod